# schema file keeps a column that i deleted in a migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I am trying to build my database from scratch. 
I have run the `rake db:reset` and `rake db:migrate`

I have edited my CreatePerformances migration not to include the filed 'file_name' (I usually would create a new migration but its a small project)

```
class CreatePerformances < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :performances do |t|
      t.date :date
      t.string :location
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

When i look at my schema.rb file it still includes the file_name field

```
.
.
.

create_table "performances", force: true do |t|
        t.string   "file_name"
        t.date     "date"
        t.string   "location"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
      end
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I tried deleting the schema.rb file and rerunning the migration. Yet the new schema generated still has file_name in it... I'm confused

Comment: I created a migration that removed the field. I still have no idea why running the migration after altering the migration file has not worked. If anybody could explain this to me i would appreciate it.